# $G/N\cong\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to answer the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N\cong\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> Show that $G=N\rtimes C$ for some subgroup $C$ of $G$.

Answer (score 4):

The short exact sequence $$1 \to N \to G \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0 $$ splits by mapping a generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ to any preimage and extending to a homomorphism. The subgroup $C$ is the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ under this section.

Comment: i didn' undersad how does that unswer the problem. Can you^please deteil more? thanks in advance

Comment: @amine I don't understand what you don't understand. You haven't told us anything about what you know/what your thoughts are on the problem.

Comment: i didn't understand why the sequence is exact and what do you mean by $C$  is the image of $Z$ under this section.?

Comment: @amine If you don't understand why the sequence is exact then you don't know what an exact sequence is. Based on your post history, you give me the impression that you are just dumping your homework questions here. I won't do all the work for you.

Comment: to prove that a sequence is exact we need to show that $Im(f_k)=ker (f_{k+1})$ but what are $f_k$ in this example and how does they satidfy $Im(f_k)=ker (f_{k+1})$?

Comment: @amine The maps $1 \to N$ and $\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ are trivial homomorphisms. $N \to G$ is the inclusion and $G \to G/N \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is the projection.

Comment: ah ok and what do you mean by The subgroup $C$ is the image of $Z$ under this section. I didn't understand that

Comment: @amine A homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to G$ such that the composition $\mathbb{Z} \to G \to \mathbb{Z}$ is the identity is called a section. The existence of such a section is equivalent to the statement that $G$ is a semidirect product of $N$ and $C \cong \mathbb{Z}$.